# How can you access "Shared" personal notebooks via rest API?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I have a shared personal notebook that I would like to access via the rest api.

I'm signing in as the user with whom the notebook has been shared (shows as "personal >> xxx.onmicrosoft.com" under the "Shared with me" section of OneNote).

Looking at this url:  [OneNote REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/onenote-get-content#root-url)

I don't see the shared notebook as a personal notebook (I do see my personal notebooks):

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks
```

It doesn't show up under sharepoint site notebooks:

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/myOrganization/siteCollections/{id}/sites/{id}/notes/notebooks
```

And it doesn't appear to be linked with a unified group.

So does anyone know how I access it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: No difference it I change to a "beta" api version.

Answer (score 1):

For enterprise notebooks, the */me* endpoint only provides access to the OneNote content that’s owned by the current user. In the coming weeks, the */me* endpoint will also include OneNote content that others have shared with the current user.

Right now, you can only use the */users/* or */users/* endpoint to access content that another user (specified in the URL) has shared with the current user.

We recently updated the docs to clarify the current behavior. We’ll update them again when the */me* scope includes shared content, and update this question too. Thanks for the feedback, SpecWin!

Comment: Hey, i am also trying to access shared notebook, but /users/ end point not working.
eg: - "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/users/notes/notebooks"

Comment: I am still not able to access to shared notebook pages. Any suggestions